# unable to move to button with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Hi I am trying to write test script using selenium webdriver to log in to ms dynamics free trial registration @ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/free-crm-trial.aspx I am  stuck at one of pages in registration
I am unable to move to button Create my account in attached screenshot

```
    //set driver settings
    driver.get("https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/free-crm-trial.aspx");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //click on get started and switch to tab 2 
    WebElement startButtton = driver.findElement(By.id("Lead:Crm:Trial"));
    startButtton.click();
    ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));

    //fill form data and click on next button
    Select droplist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_SelectedRegion")));   
    droplist.selectByVisibleText("India");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement FirstName = driver.findElement(By.name("StepsData.FirstName"));
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
            wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(FirstName));
    WebElement FirstName1 = driver.findElement(By.name("StepsData.FirstName"));
    FirstName1.sendKeys("gayatri");

    WebElement LastName = driver.findElement(By.name("StepsData.LastName"));
    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(LastName));
    WebElement LastName2 = driver.findElement(By.name("StepsData.LastName"));
    LastName2.sendKeys("kulkarni");

    WebElement EmailAddress = driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_EmailAddress"));
    EmailAddress.sendKeys("abc@abc.com");

    WebElement PhoneNumber = driver.findElement(By.id("PhoneNumber"));
    PhoneNumber.sendKeys("8888888888");

    WebElement OrganizationName = driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_OrganizationName"));
    OrganizationName.sendKeys("company");

    Select language = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_OrganizationLanguage")));   
    language.selectByVisibleText("English");

    Select OrgSize = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_OrgSize")));   
    OrgSize.selectByValue("50-249");

    WebElement NextButton = driver.findElement(By.id("MultiPageLayout_Next"));
    NextButton.click();

    //fill form data and click on create my account button
    WebElement UserId = driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_UserId"));
    UserId.sendKeys("gayatrik2512");
    WebElement DomainName = driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_DomainName"));
    DomainName.sendKeys("meetQA");

    WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.id("Password"));
    Password.sendKeys("xxxxx@123");
    WebElement Repassword = driver.findElement(By.id("RePassword"));
    Repassword.sendKeys("xxxxx@123");

    WebElement EmailCheck = driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_EmailCheckboxChecked"));
    if(!(EmailCheck.isSelected()))          
    EmailCheck.click();

    WebElement PhoneCheck = driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_PhoneAgreementCheckboxChecked"));
    if(!(PhoneCheck.isSelected()))          
        EmailCheck.click();

    WebElement PartCheck = driver.findElement(By.id("StepsData_PartnerAgreementCheckboxChecked"));
    if(!(PartCheck.isSelected()))           
        PartCheck.click();

    **Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("MultiPageLayout_Next"))).click().build().perform();**

    PFA screenshot
```

[image]

Comment: where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: unable to click last button                                                                                    >> act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("MultiPageLayout_Next"))).click().build().perform();

Comment: What happens when you try to `click`? Is an exception thrown? Does the click just not fire? Also, any chance you can include html for the button in the question?

Comment: Please put the html part you are trying to interact with as we can't see the html from a screenshot.  Based on what I'm seeing you shouldn't need the moveToElement but just the click as mentioned by mrfreester.  However, in the post below it looks like you are struggling with getting the focus to change...which would indicate you are not finding the element correctly and it's just firing the click at the present location instead of on the element.  We need the HTML...

Comment: I have mentioned url Its one of the pages @  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/free-crm-trial.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I cannot comment as I do not have the required reputation, but why are you using moveToElement? If you want to click, try this:

`findElement(By.id("MultiPageLayout_Next")).click()`

Comment: Its not working for me When I run the script, user id input box remains focused

Comment: getting exception as when executed for classname selector org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Comment: try this, as the previous one I tested on Selenium IDE on Firefox, for this one I used your code to run and It was able to click on the button on Chrome

`findElement(By.id("MultiPageLayout_Next")).click()`

Comment: @gayatri could you please try that, let me edit my answer as well.

Comment: I tried driver.findElement(By.id("MultiPageLayout_Next")).click(); But  still getting same problem Script haults at screen attached